# How to give name to NPM package from GitHub (vuejs package)

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, package.json

I fork a git repo of vuejs to be specifically edited just for my project. I installed it successfully by

```
npm install bondythegreat/vue-input-tag --save
```

it creates

```
"vue-input-tag": "github:bondythegreat/vue-input-tag",
```

and I can see it in the node_modules directory after installation.

But with the original package, I can easily use it by calling it in my JavaScript code like this:

```
import taginput from 'vue-input-tag'
```

but how can I call this package of the forked code? Because it throws an error when I `npm run watch`.

Comment: And that error would be.....?

Comment: I don't think you should have a `/` in your package name.

Comment: the error is:
This dependency was not found:

* @bondythegreat/vue-input-tag in ./~/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,...

Answer (score 1):

Either set your package name to just

```
"name": "vue-input-tag",
```

or revert back to your [commit](https://github.com/bondythegreat/vue-input-tag/commit/7a021e3d1110bed3f74914d0105d26c679ee16a9) where you used a [scoped package name](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope)

```
"name": "@bondythegreat/vue-input-tag",
```

and use

```
import taginput from '@bondythegreat/vue-input-tag'
```

Comment: the error is:
This dependency was not found:

* @bondythegreat/vue-input-tag in ./~/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["es2015",{"modules":false}]]}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/forms/TagsField.vue

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @bondythegreat/vue-input-tag

hmm..what i dont understand is why in the original package there's no such error but the forked one throw this error?

Comment: @bondythegreat because you made the package name into a path which messes with a bunch of things